# Will this iptables rule accept all traffic, making my other rules useless?

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, firewall, iptables

I've adapted this iptables configuration from someone else, and am trying to figure out whether it's doing what I want it to. It is supposed to run on a coreos server, with several docker containers, and function as a webserver.

So ports 80 and 443 should be open, icmp traffic is allowed and I need ssh access. I've rate limited ssh and put it on a different port and traffic is dropped by default. As far as I can tell it's all good. However one rule I don't understand: `-A INPUT -i eth1 -j ACCEPT`. I believe this rule is there to allow docker containers to talk to eachother.

But will that rule not open up the entire interface to the www? What does this rule do exactly? Do I need it for docker, or can I omit it?

This is the entire config:

```
  *filter
  :INPUT DROP [0:0]
  :FORWARD DROP [0:0]
  :OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]

  # Loopback interface
  -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT

  # What does this rule do exactly? Do I need it?
  -A INPUT -i eth1 -j ACCEPT

  # Already established connections
  -A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

  # Web services
  -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
  -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT

  # Rate limit SSH
  -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 2233 -m state --state NEW -m recent --set --name SSH
  -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 2233 -m state --state NEW -m recent --update --seconds 60 --hitcount 4 --rttl --name SSH -j DROP
  -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 2233 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT

  # ICMP traffic
  -A INPUT -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 0 -j ACCEPT
  -A INPUT -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 3 -j ACCEPT
  -A INPUT -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 11 -j ACCEPT
  COMMIT
```

Output of `ip route list`

```
default via {ip here}.64.1 dev eth0  proto static
10.18.0.0/16 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.18.0.5
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0  proto kernel  scope link  src 172.17.0.1
{ip here}.64.0/18 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src {ip here}.86.198
```

Related:

- https://serverfault.com/questions/705192/iptables-rule-set-so-that-a-docker-container-can-access-a-service-on-a-host-ip
- https://www.jimmycuadra.com/posts/securing-coreos-with-iptables/
- https://gist.github.com/jimmycuadra/fe79ae8857f3f0d0cae1
- https://gist.github.com/socketwiz/d6fe23d19180a1ad8b5a

Comment: Docker automatically sets up appropriate iptables rules.

Comment: @DanielB Hmm ok, so what purpose could this rule serve? It is a coreos digitalocean server, and apparently it has an eth0 and eth1 interface. Is that standard for coreos? Or digital ocean servers? Can I just omit this rule?

Comment: The answer to your question hinges on whether you have only one interface (*eth1*) or several. Do you have several?If so, is *eth1* connected to your LAN, while *eth0* is connected to the WAN? And then, if you have several, do you have other *FORWARD* rules? A proper answer requires this extra info. In doubt, pls post your routing table.

Comment: @MariusMatutiae Ok added. As I said in the comment above, apparently I have an eth0 and eth1 interface. Not sure what is connected to what. I am assuming that this is just the standard networking setup for a digital ocean droplet. I'm not setting any other rules than the ones posted above.

Comment: Hm, if you have an `eth1` interface, it isn’t up. Please provide the output of `ip link`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your routing table, it appears you have **no** *eth1* interface, which is quite strange, for  a router.

The **normal** configuration for a router is: one interface (*eth0*) connected to the outer world, another interface (*eth1*) **is** your LAN. Then the *iptables* rules make sense: they strictly control input on interface *eth0*, while they allow everything to flow inside your LAN. For this to work, however, you will also need:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -j ACCEPT 
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

Without the first one, which flatly contradicts your policy (*:FORWARD DROP [0:0]*) pcs inside your LAN will never be able to talk to the outside world; the second one also makes it possible for pcs inside your LAN to talk to the outside world, by rewriting the source address of your packets to that of the outer interface of your router, which will allow replies to come back, and then your router takes care *automagically* of sending the reply packet to its intended recipient. If you do not wish pcs on your LAN to talk to the world, you can drop both rules.

As your set of rules and your interfaces stand instead, since there is no *eth1* interface (and hence **no LAN**), the rule you are fretting about is utterly useless.  The rules simply make the current pc a well-policed one, with some services accessible from outside, but without performing the functions generally associated with a router, *i.e.* NAT and firewall for your LAN.

How to proceed depends on what you are aiming to achieve.

Comment: I might be misunderstanding, but it isn't meant to be a router but a webserver. It doesn't have to route traffic to other computers inside the LAN. Also, with the current setup everything works as expected. I'm just trying to see whether the current setup contains unnecessary rules and is otherwise correctly configured.

Comment: @ismay And you think I have not answered your question clearly enough?

Comment: No need to be sarcastic, I'm just trying to understand your answer. To be clear: no, I don't understand how this answers my question exactly.

Comment: @ismay: I said that the rule *-A INPUT -i eth1 -j ACCEPT* is useless because you do not have an *eth1* interface, or, if your prefer, it is **never** invoked. I also stated you that your current set of rules makes your machine **a well-policed one**, which means it is well defended. In other words, you have exposed to the world the **minimum** attack surface, given the services you intend to provide from your digitalocean server. In other words, you cannot do better.

Comment: @ismay Sure, no problem, any time.